# reading from a file in c/qt creator

Tags: c, qt-creator

When I try to run the code below, it gets stuck for some reason. It doesn't even print the "test" string before while loop. I'm writing on QT Creator.

```
void textInput(){
    int n;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("book.txt","r");

       printf("test");
       while((userInput = getc(f)) != EOF && (bufferChars < BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH)){

           if(userInput == '\n'){
               buffer[bufferChars] = 0x00;
               tokenizeLine();
               bufferChars = 0;
               while (nthToken != 0) {
                       token[nthToken] = NULL;
                       nthToken--;
               }
               continue;
           }

           buffer[bufferChars++] = userInput;
       }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



    textInput();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you develop C code in QtCreator?! Also, show the whole code, is the function even called? Also, retag the question. This is not related to Qt, but QtCreator! Moreover, you could write `FILE *f = fopen("book.txt","r");` in one line.

Comment: i'm trying to develop something with pthreads. this is just the very beginning.

Comment: Did you verify that `book.txt` is an existing file?

Comment: Yes. When i write putchar(userInput) right after while line it prints but  otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not using Qt creator but I guess it runs your program in its own environment redirecting its output and showing it in a window or whatever. If this is the case then the following can be the problem: The standard library linked to your program may detect the type of stdout handle (whether its file, console output, or pipe, ..) and it may or may not use buffering for it. In case of pipes it usually buffers. In this case you may have to insert `fflush(stdout);` after every function call that writes to the standard output. I ran into similar problems before...